# jsDoc @constructs not inherited by extending Objects?

Tags: mootools, phpstorm, jsdoc

I'm using @lends + @constructs + @augments for MooTools Class definitions (custom namespace variation), however I'm getting some inspection issues in PhpStorm in extending classes if I don't include an initialize in the extending class with a @constructs above it.  Is it not possible in jsDoc to omit initialize in extending classes OR is PhpStorm inspection just not working correctly?

```
new Class('Validator.Generic',
/**
 * @lends Validator.Generic
 */
{
    /**
     * @constructs
     */
     initialize:function(){}
}

new Class('Validator.Regex',
/**
 * @augments Validator.Generic
 * @lends Validator.Regex
 */
{
    //PhpStorm inspection reports unrecognized symbol Regex unless
    //I add a method with @constructs here, even though the class
    //it augments has a constructor
});
```

I've tried variations as well.  It only works if I add an initialize to the extending class (e.g. Validator.Regex) along with a @constructs tag to the docblock.  This of course is not ideal.

Comment: add /** @class Validator.Regex */ above new Class('Validator.Regex') - this should help

Comment: @lena Make this an answer so I can give you credit.  This does appear to be what I'm after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lena's answer partially works, but was still arbitrarily failing inspection in seemingly identical situations. I changed my approach and thought about the literal meanings of the tag names. Conclusion: '@class' is to define a type (pseudo statically), '@augments' and '@lends' in the context of a prototype based languages should then imply Instance extensions. This is intuitive in hind sight. All inspections now pass with the following syntax.

`/**
  * @class Validator.Regex
  * @augments {Validator.Generic}
  */
 new Class('Validator.Regex',
     /**
      * @lends {Validator.Regex}
      */
     {}
 );`

Comment: Too bad this syntax has to be so verbose, but again PhpStorm regex replace in path was a big help to speed up the process.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `/** @class Validator.Regex */` above `new Class('Validator.Regex')`

Comment: See the answer I added for details